# Play WS max connection

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket, playframework-2.0, typesafe-activator

We have three components(A,B and C). "A" sends data to "B" and "B" process data and post it to "C" using play WS. We have a situation when "C" is slow in processing the data, Time out happens in "B". But there is lot of data inward flow in "B" and keep posting it to "C" causes the whole system to run out of memory and finally crash. Is there a way to limit the number of WS request in "B" ? searched the play WS API but no luck. How should this be handled? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not about max connection number and not anything else api related. This problem is common in distributed systems and named **"Fast producer and slow consumer"**. There is more solution then I could write here but a short list will be:

- Message Queues (for ActiveMQ see [Slow Consumer Handling](http://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling.html))
- BackPressure (this is a method that can be explained with one sentence; "Producer sends data only when consumer asks", BTW, Akka Streams makes this available in an elegant way)
- Scale (the most straight method if you want your system faster, just increase nmber of your consumers and load balance requests between them or make **the consumer** faster)

Edit:
According to [Documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaWS#Configuring-AsyncHttpClientConfig) you can set a max. connection per host or total for client library, as I mentioned above the right way is improving architecture but this may also help and save the day. Also check [reference.conf](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/resources/reference.conf) for all configuration options.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The product is in the final stage of GA and we dont have time to do big changes on the design. The slowdown happens only in the negative scenario on a DB transaction. To be on safer side we are planning to handle this. Wanted to know if Play WS is already supporting this? and if yes How?

Comment: I edited my answer for some "save the day" approach you want

Comment: If I am not wrong AsyncHttpClientConfig is a different implementation right. I use WS for REST. Or by configuring the parameter it will work for WS as well https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaWS#Configuring-WS.

Comment: From documentation, "WSClient is a wrapper around the underlying AsyncHttpClient. It is useful for defining multiple clients with different profiles, or using a mock."

Comment: Than you let me try it out.

Comment: Hüseyin Zengin The following was configure in application.conf "play.ws.ning.maxConnectionsTotal = 2 play.ws.ning.maxConnectionsTotal = 2".       But I see no effect in socket open/close (User yourkit to monitor socket). Am I missing some thing. I am new in this area. Should I have to implement AsyncHttpClient insted of WS.

Comment: what is  the exact version of play you are using?

Comment: the version of play that is I am using is 2.4.0

Comment: Hüseyin Zengin do you think I am missing some thing over here?

Comment: I don't think so, "play.ws.ning.maxConnectionsTotal = 2" should do the work, you are using this config in your client, right?

Comment: I have a application that Post REST data. For this we are using WS and I have configured this in "application.config" . I am sure it is not working.

Comment: make sure they are in application.conf file under src/main/resources directory

Answer (score 0):

Consider Akka and some of throttling algorithms: http://letitcrash.com/post/28901663062/throttling-messages-in-akka-2